# Mod rewrite to redirect to 404 if filename is followed by other characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website I have files index.php,home.php,about.php

And The full url is

```
http://example.com/about.php
```

and the wired thing is that

```
 http://example.com/about.php#foobar
```

also goes to the about page . I want to block anything after my files name and redirect it to 404.

I copied this from a similar post :

```
  Rewriterule ([a-zA-Z]+).([a-zA-Z]+) - [L]
Rewriterule ([a-zA-Z]+).([a-zA-Z]+) - [R=404,L]
```

Its not working. can you help me please?

Edit: its not a hashmark related question.

I want to redirect 404 a url with a trailing path.

Comment: @Gaborbakos please reread the question

Comment: So you want `/about.php#foobar` to be treated differently from `/about.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this :

```
 AcceptPathInfo Off
```

Source :  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AcceptPathInfo